# Checking a number for parity

Tags: java, numbers

To check that both expressions are true, you need to use &&. Syntax
expression1 && expression2
In this problem, you need to check that the number passed is positive AND even

my code:

```
public static boolean check(int num) {
        boolean result = (num == 1 && num % 2 == 0);
        return result;
}
```

test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertFalse(LogicAnd.check(-1));
    assertFalse(LogicAnd.check(1));
    assertTrue(LogicAnd.check(2));
}
```

error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
>
> at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)   at
> org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:512)  at
> org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)  at
> org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:51)  at
> ru.job4j.sentence.LogicAndTest.test(LogicAndTest.java:14)     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

Please help me to correct

Comment: It will never be the case a number equals one and is divisible by two.

Comment: Look at your logic. It will be false for all inputs. You're saying that the number "has to equal 1 AND be even"

Comment: I think you need to replace `==` with `>=`

Comment: *parity* is usually defined as the sum of the bits mod 2, but your test only looks at the low-order bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completed the task.The error was related to num == 1. It was necessary to display num >= 1